# Macro to Include Based on Variable Record Names

Tags: sas

I'm attempting to create a macro to apply to number tables where it would only keep  rows where the Account_Description equals 'Office Equipment', 'Computer Peripherals' or 'Equipment Rental'.

So for example, I have the marcro code (my version does not work) followed by the tables, which are each followed by the Macro, respectively.

You may say, why not just copy and paste-what I'm asking is a simplistic view of my question as I have 13 other sets of Account_Description pools that I would like to turn into Macros as well.

```
 %MACRO Total_Minor_Equipment;
 %if &Account_Description = 'Office Equipment' 
 or &Account_Description = 'Computer Peripherals' 
 or &Account_Description = 'Equipment Rental';
 %MEND Total_Minor_Equipment; 

 Data June_2019_v2; 
 set  June_2019_v1;
 run;
 %Total_Minor_Equipment

 Data July_2019_v2; 
 set  July_2019_v1;
 run;
 %Total_Minor_Equipment

 Data Aug_2019_v2; 
 set  Aug_2019_v1;
 run;
 %Total_Minor_Equipment
```

Comment: I really, really think you need to go back three steps and undo what you did to split these datasets. You're now stuck looping every single process instead of using SAS efficiently here, you're duplicating the work required.

Comment: Each dataset is separate table from a direct proc import. These datasets were never split.

Comment: Since you're doing the exact same thing to each one I'd still highly recommend going back and combining them into one. Unless you're running into massive space issues it will save you hours of work and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a brief study of SAS datastep and macro may help you since you have it a bit confused. Remember, anything that goes inside a macro gets resolved during compile time and output is actually code that gets executed during runtime. So when you call your macro outside a datastep, it writes out some arbitrary code outside the datastep which will fail to execute. Also you seem to mix up up macro `%if` with a datstep `if`.

What you need to do is:

```
 %MACRO Total_Minor_Equipment;
 if Account_Description in ('Office Equipment', 'Computer Peripherals', 'Equipment Rental');
 %MEND Total_Minor_Equipment; 

 Data June_2019_v2; 
   set  June_2019_v1;
   %Total_Minor_Equipment
 run;
```

You could use the `IN` operator instead or `OR` here.

assuming the field name is `Account_Description`. If indeed the macro variable `Account_Description` contains the actual field name then you should change it to `&Account_Description` as you had it before.

Comment: Or better still forget the macro and just copy the IF (or WHERE) statement into each step. If the list of values changes then put it into a macro VARIABLE.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than store the account description classification rules in source code, use a second data set to map the descriptions to the class.  The data set can be joined to the original data, or be used as the basis of a custom format that returns the class value.

As in your prior question, recommend stacking all the monthly data sets as one (per SET statement shown by @Reeza).  (If you had previously split them out from a single table, maybe don't do that).  Apply the format to the description to compute the desired pool.  Use `WHERE` and `BY` statements in downstream analytics when month-wise grouping or segregation called for.

```
data account_pool_cntlin;
  length description pool fmtname $32 ;
  retain fmtname "$acctpool";
  input description:  & pool:; datalines;
  Office Equipment      Minor_Equipment
  Computer Peripherals  Minor_Equipment
  Equipment Rental      Minor_Equipment
  Shipping Container    Major Equipment
  BigRig Tractor        Major Equipment
  BigRig Tailer         Major Equipment
  Baseball Cap          Major League Equipment
  Baseball Uniforms     Major League Equipment
  Baseball Bases        Major League Equipment
run;

proc format cntlin=account_pool_cntlin (
  rename = (
    description = start
    pool = label
  ))
;
run;

data want;
  set Jan_2019 Feb_2019 ... Aug_2019 indsname=dataset_name;

  mon_year = dataset_name;

  pool = put (account_description, $acctpool.);
run;
```

Note: A deeper understanding and application of formats in your analyses may result in code in which there is no need to compute the `pool` variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this macro, if you want to call macro manual several times:

```
%MACRO Total_Minor_Equipment(base_table_name,out_table_name);
   Data &out_table_name; 
      set  &base_table_name;
      if Account_Description in ('Office Equipment', 'Computer Peripherals', 'Equipment Rental');
   run;
%MEND Total_Minor_Equipment; 

%Total_Minor_Equipment(June_2019_v2, June_2019_v1);
%Total_Minor_Equipment(July_2019_v2, July_2019_v1);
%Total_Minor_Equipment(Aug_2019_v2, Aug_2019_v1);
```

If you want to do it dynamically, calling macro one time (from _v1 to _v2):

```
%let mask_list = June_2019_ July_2019_ Aug_2019_;

%MACRO Total_Minor_Equipment(tmask_list);
   %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&tmask_list,%str( )));
      %let name&i = %scan(&tmask_list,&i,%str( )); 
      Data &&name&i.v2; 
         set  &&name&i.v1;
         if Account_Description in ('Office Equipment', 'Computer Peripherals', 'Equipment Rental');
      run;
   %end;
%MEND Total_Minor_Equipment; 

%Total_Minor_Equipment(&mask_list);
```

Comment: In addition, if you know all names(masks) of months, there is opportunity to improve the algorithm iterating by years, for example(But you should manually initialize the names). Or you can change format of naming the months to sas default formats, and then there will be different solution to integrate by months and years:)

Comment: @Raven you are welcome! Please, check your previous question, and mark correct answer;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend stacking all the data sets at once and filtering at once.

```
%let dset_list = June_2019_v1 July_2019_v1 Aug_2019_v1;
data want;
 set  &dset_list indsname=source;
 input_file = source;
 if account_description in ('Office Equipment', 'Computer Peripherals', 'Equipment Rental');
run;
```

That will combine all the data sets, filter it, and add a record indicating which record belonged to each individual data set.

Comment: I'm not seeing the addition of the record indicating which record belonged to each individual data set. Is there a way to get those code to produce separate tables for each datasets?

Comment: It would be in the input_file variable, assuming you followed the code exactly. I really don't recommend working with multiple files the way you have been, you're making your job harder and the two to three hours it would take to understand by group processing is well worth the time.